# Configure Hypnotoad to use a different user/group

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to my [Mojolicious::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite) that is started under `root` using [hypnotoad](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Server::Hypnotoad) to run under a different user/group (`foobar`/`foobar` in the below example).

I'm using the following configuration call:

```
app->config(
    hypnotoad => {
        listen => ["http://*:$API_Port"],
        user   => 'foobar',
        group  => 'foobar',
        proxy  => 1,
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, it appears that all children still run under `root`, and any files created in routes also use the `root` and `0644` instead of the `foobar` and `0664`.

The docs for hypnotoad appear to be rather sparse, as the only reference I could find to changing the user/group thus far are in a github issue:  https://github.com/kraih/mojo/issues/733

Answer (score 3):

The cpan module, [Mojolicious::Plugin::SetUserGroup](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::SetUserGroup), appears to solve this:

```
# Mojolicious::Lite
plugin SetUserGroup => { user => $user, group => $group };
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the simple solution! Just edit your Systemd Unit file and add two options: User and Group...

Example:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Perl service
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
# put here other service requirements

[Service]
User=testuser1
Group=testuser1
Type=simple
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=testperlservice
PIDFile=/home/testuser1/tmp/testperlservice.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hypnotoad /home/testuser1/script/test -f
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/hypnotoad -s /home/testuser1/script/test
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/hypnotoad /home/testuser1/script/test
```